# Date value changes when updating time value in datagridview when using MySqlCommandBuilder

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime, datagridview

I have table (test) that contains two fields such as

dt_id (datatype-int)(primary key),

dt (datatype-datetime)

I am displaying the date and time separately in datagridview using this SQL query.

```
string query = "select `test`.`dt_id`,`test`.`dt` as 'date', `test`.`dt` as 'time' from test";
```

and I am displaying the date and time in following format

```
dataGridView1.Columns["date"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
dataGridView1.Columns["time"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "hh:mm tt";
```

I have update button with the following code.

```
private void buttonUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MySqlCommandBuilder cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
   dataAdapter.Update(dataTable);
}
```

Lets say, datagridview shows following data

dt_id ---------- date ---------- time

1 ----------- 15/08/1947 ----- 07:22 PM

I change time column value to 06:22 PM, after clicking on update button. update is success, but when I display the data again in datagridview, date value has been changed to today's date.

dt_id ---------- date ---------- time

1 ----------- 27/07/2015 ----- 06:22 PM

Actually the date value is affected in MYSQL database.

How do I change or update time value without changing its date value in datagridview?

Comment: Is your column date and time are 2 separate columns or a single datetime column?

Comment: @chandran its a single datetime column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok when you are trying to update time only value in a combined date_time value it will update the date as well.

Below update query will update only the time of the datetime column

```
update testing set date_time=concat(substr(date_time,1,11),'20:21:00') where id=2;
```

Existing data:

```
+----+---------------------+
| id |date_time            |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | 1987-03-20 18:10:00 |
|  2 | 1989-03-20 19:32:00 |
+----+---------------------+
```

After Update only time:

```
+----+---------------------+
| id | date_time           |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | 1987-03-20 13:00:00 |
|  2 | 1989-03-20 20:21:00 |
+----+---------------------+
```

Comment: Its working. But I need to change the update query of a dataapater everytime through datagridview events which requires extra coding. I think its better to have two separate fields for date and time. The time field has to be TIME datatype in mysql. This reduces the coding. Anyways thanks.